# Mosquitto broker setup bridge in Raspberry Pi to IoT Hub SAS token

Tags: raspberry-pi, azure-iot-hub, mosquitto, sas-token

Because IoT Hub is not a broker, I want to use a Raspberry Pi as a broker which devices can communicate with, and the Raspberry Pi sends messages it receives to IoT Hub.
After intallation of Mosquitto on Raspberry this is my file of configuration mosquitto:

```
connection iothub-bridge   
log_type all  
address your hub.azure-devices.net:8883  
remote_username your hub.azure-devices.net/your device  
remote_password sas token  
remote_clientid your device  
bridge_cafile /home/pi/baltimore.pem  
try_private false  
cleansession true  
start_type automatic  
bridge_insecure false  
bridge_protocol_version mqttv311  
bridge_tls_version tlsv1.2  
notifications false  
notification_topic events/  
topic  devices/Your device/messages/events/
```

The problem is a SAS token is used for few hours and will expire, I want a solution to replace SAS TOKEN and work for forever.

Comment: Hi Youcef, the configuration in its current state is unreadable. Could you update the formatting?
As for your question, have you looked into using IoT Edge as a transparent gateway? There are good resources [here](http://busbyland.com/connect-mqtt-client-to-azure-iot-edge/) and [here](http://busbyland.com/mosquitto-mqtt-broker-to-iot-hub-iot-edge/) on how to achieve your goal.

Comment: Yes exactly what i followed to set up this configuration, need answer for the problem of SAS Token ?? Thank you

Comment: You can specify the expiration date for a SAS token, I think the maximum is 365 days, but *forever* is not a possibility. Alternatively you can use [X509](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-devguide-security#supported-x509-certificates), they also come with an expiration date.

Comment: how can i generate certaficate x509 for this case ? do you have a tutorial step by step please ? not a documentation of microsoft because is not helpful for me , thanks

Answer (score 3):

Glad you enjoyed my blog posts :-).

As Matthijs said, maximum in device explorer or similar for a SAS token generation is 365 days, but with the [Azure IoT CLI](https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-cli-extension) you can go much longer.  For example, this command creates one for 10 years  (315,360,000 seconds)

az iot hub generate-sas-token -n [your iot hub] -d [your device id] --du 315360000

As Matthijs also said, you cannot generate one that never expires.  I tried generating one for 100 years (3,153,600,000 seconds) and it seems to have worked

I will caveat that I didn't actually try to connect the devices above to IoT Hub.

With that said, it's not a great security practice to have SAS tokens for that long, but as long as you are clear on the risks involved, I think it's technically feasible.

Comment: I was curious so I tried connecting with a SAS token good for 100 years and it appears to work fine.